# Is it possible to view my HTML files in Rstudio's Viewer instead of a new generated Rstudio preview window?

Tags: knitr, rstudio

I'm wondering if it's possible to view html files in Rstudio's Viewer panel as opposed to having a new Preview window pop up everytime I hit the Knit HTML button?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not possible at the moment, but you can file a feature request to http://support.rstudio.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RStudio v 1.0.44

Under Tools:Global Options:R Markdown there is an option 'Show output preview in'.  Choices are 'Window', 'Viewer Pane' or '(none)'

Comment: Thanks, I think this feature wasn't available at the time when I first asked.  Great to finally see it implemented!